# How do I pass an argument to the parent constructor in oop PHP?

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

I am trying to instantiate two objects from a base class and and pass an argument to the parent class constructor from the child class constructor. This doesn't seem to be working. It acts as if the objects are not even sub objects of the parent class. I do not know what I am doing wrong.

I've tried rearranging the includes, passing no arguments (that results in an error, "expects an argument"), and other tinkering to no avail.

The parent class:

```php
class SuperHero {
    private $health;
    private $name;
    private $isDead;

    public function __construct($name) {
        $this->name;
        $this->isDead = false;
    }

    // ...

    public function attack($opponent) { 
        echo $this->name.' attacks '.$opponent->name.'!<br>';
        $dmg = mt_rand(1, 10);
        $opponentHealth = determineHealth($opponent, $dmg);
        echo $opponent->name.' has '.$opponentHealth.' health left!<br>';
    }

    // ...
```

The child class:

```php
<?php
require_once('SuperHero.php');
class Batman extends SuperHero {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct('Batman');
        $this->health = mt_rand(1, 1000);
    }

}
```

The executed script:

```php
require_once('Batman.php');
require_once('Superman.php');

$h1 = new Batman;
$h2 = new Superman;

echo $h1->name.' is starting with '.$h1->health.' health!<br>';
echo $h2->name.' is starting with '.$h2->health.' health!<br>';

while($h1->getIsDead() == false && $h2->getIsDead() == false){    
    $h1->attack($h2);  
    $h2->attack($h1);
}
```

Actual results

```
is starting with 317 health!
Superman is starting with 300 health!
attacks !
```

Expected results

```
Batman is starting with 317 health!
Superman is starting with 300 health!
Batman attacks Superman!
```

Comment: You actually never set `$this->name` at any point.

Comment: You forgot `$this->name = $name;` in `Superhero` constructor.

Comment: Also, you are trying to access `$opponent->name`, and `$h1->health` but `name` and `health` are private. You'd need getters to access those properties.

Comment: Finally, your whole design is bugged. It makes it possible for Superman to defeat Batman; and we all know that's impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parent class' constructor looks like this

```
public function __construct($name) {
    $this->name;
    $this->isDead = false;
}
```

`$this->name;` alone does *nothing*, it attempts to get that value. You need to assign it a value, by doing

```
$this->name = $name;
```

Then, all your attributes are *private*, meaning that you cannot access them by doing `$batman->name`. You will need to implement a getter for that, `$batman->getName()` (for each property that you want to get). If they were public, you could get them by doing `$batman->name`, but then you can overwrite it as well by `$batman->name = 'Robin';`. Better use a getter.

Further, `determineHealth()` should probably a method of the class and called on the `$opponent` object, instead of an actual function.

```
class SuperHero {
    private $health;
    private $name;
    private $isDead;

    public function __construct($name, $health) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->health = $health;
        $this->isDead = false;
    }

    public function attack($opponent) { 
        $dmg = mt_rand(1, 10);
        echo $this->getName().' attacks '.$opponent->getName().' with '.$dmg." damage. ";
        $opponentHealth = $opponent->determineHealth($dmg);
        echo $opponent->getName().' has '.$opponentHealth." health left!<br />\n";
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getHealth() {
        return $this->health;
    }

    public function isDead() {
        return $this->isDead;
    }

    public function determineHealth($health) {
        $this->health -= $health;
        if ($this->health <= 0) {
            $this->health = 0;
            $this->isDead = true;
        }
        return $this->health;
    }
}

class Batman extends SuperHero {
    public function __construct() {
        $health = mt_rand(1, 1000);
        parent::__construct('Batman', $health);
    }
}

class Superman extends SuperHero {
    public function __construct() {
        $health = mt_rand(1, 1000);
        parent::__construct('Superman', $health);
    }
}

$h1 = new Batman;
$h2 = new Superman;


echo $h1->getName().' is starting with '.$h1->getHealth()." health!<br>\n";
echo $h2->getName().' is starting with '.$h2->getHealth()." health!<br>\n";

$h1->attack($h2);  
$h2->attack($h1);
```

Output:

```
Batman is starting with 445 health!<br>
Superman is starting with 229 health!<br>
Batman attacks Superman with 5 damage. Superman has 224 health left!<br />
Superman attacks Batman with 9 damage. Batman has 436 health left!<br />
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/aDegT

Answer (score 1):

The `name` and `health` members of superclass are not available in subclass as they are private.

Either you should change them to public or you should create public getters and setters and use them instead.

Answer (score 0):

> Private Variable can't be inherited.

```
    <?php
class SuperHero {
    private $health;
    private $name;
    private $isDead;

    public function __construct($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->isDead = false;
    }

    public function name()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function attack($opponent) { 
        echo $this->name.' attacks '.$opponent->name.'!<br>';
        $dmg = mt_rand(1, 10);
        $opponentHealth = determineHealth($opponent, $dmg);
        echo $opponent->name.' has '.$opponentHealth.' health left!<br>';
    }
}

class Batman extends SuperHero {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct('Batman');
        $this->health = mt_rand(1, 1000);
    }

}
class Superman extends SuperHero {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct('Superman');
        $this->health = mt_rand(1, 1000);
    }

}

$h1 = new Batman;
$h2 = new Superman;

echo $h1->name().' is starting with '.$h1->health.' health!<br>';
echo $h2->name().' is starting with '.$h2->health.' health!<br>';

while($h1->getIsDead == false && $h2->getIsDead == false){    
    $h1->attack($h2);  
    $h2->attack($h1);
}

?>
```

> Here in Parent class **function name()** will return the name that is passed from **parent::__construct('Name')**.

Output

```
Batman is starting with 327 health!
Superman is starting with 842 health!
Batman attacks Superman!
```